# form add more button, dynamic insert object values react 17.0.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form which has add more row and delete the row, this feature is working perfect
but i am stuck with values inside it.

Here is my state

```
const [row, setRow] = useState([{ scheduleNumber: "", quantity: "", payableTo: "", remarks: "", costJson: {} }]);
```

In the above object all the values are stored except **scheduleNumber** and **costJson**, I am stuck here

Here is the add more button onclick triggered

```
const handleaddmoreSchedules = () => {
    setRow([...row, { scheduleNumber: "", quantity: "", payableTo: "", remarks: "", costJson: {} }]);
}
```

Here is my delete row

```
const handleDeleteSchedule = index => {
    const list = [...row];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setRow(list);
}
```

onchange function

```
const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...row, ...schuduleNumber];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setRow(list);
    console.log(row) //**this shows all except scheduleNumber and CostJson
};
```

Here is my Form

```
{row.map((x,i) => {
    return(
        <Form.Control as="select" value={x.scheduleNumber} name="scheduleNo" onChange={setSelectedScheduleNumber} >
        <Form.Control type="text" name="payableTo" value={x.payableTo} onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)} >
        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} name="remarks" value={x.remarks} onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)} >
        <Form.Control type="text" name="payableTo" value={x.payableTo} onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)} >
        
        {costs?.map((cost) => {
            return (
                <Form.Control
                    type="number"
                    name={cost.key}
                    min="1"
                    max={cost.value}
                    onChange={handleCostInput}
                />
... other end tags
```

there is an differenct onchange function for **scheduleNumber** and **costJson**

How do i combine all together ?

Comment: Did you try `console.log(list)` instead of `console.log(row)`?

Comment: [{…}, "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0"] is the output of console.log(list);

Comment: Can you show me the output of `console.log(row)`?

Comment: https://imgur.com/Z6MbYXH Here i have updated the screenshot of this

Comment: Are you trying to combine the value of **scheduleNumber** and **costJson** to setRow? In other words, are you trying to insert the value of **scheduleNumber** and **costJson** to _row_ ??

Comment: yes, i am trying to insert, so that i will have one object for the the entire form